# Firebase crashing on addListenerForSingleValueEvent

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im developing an app on android which has this block of code:

```
if (ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebaseAutenticacao().getCurrentUser() != null) {
    DatabaseReference ref = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebaseReference().child(ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebaseAutenticacao().getUid()).
            child("user type");
    ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            usertype = (String) dataSnapshot.getValue();
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}
```

this is called right on OnCreate method, so its called every time the main activity comes up. So when I go to another activity and comes back, it crashes because of this block of code. So the method addListenerForSingleValueEvent does not accept another adding. Any suggestions to fix it?

Class ConfiguracaoDatabase is:

```
public class ConfiguracaoFirebase {

    private static DatabaseReference referenciaFirebase;
    private static FirebaseAuth autenticacao;

    public static DatabaseReference getFirebaseReference(){
        if (referenciaFirebase == null){
            referenciaFirebase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        }

        return referenciaFirebase;
    }

    public static FirebaseAuth getFirebaseAutenticacao(){
        if (autenticacao == null){
            autenticacao = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        }
        return autenticacao;
    }
}
```

Database structure on Firebase is quite simple:
[Firebase DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yMYT.png)

Comment: Hi juliodidier, Welcome to SO. Please post the stack trace  so that we can help you.

Comment: can you add your database structure ? what are you trying to do with the value in the onCreate?

Comment: do you need to keep watching when this value change?

Comment: no, just need to check it once and take an action based on the retrieved result

Comment: can you add ur logcat?

Comment: did you tried with onResume method ? (if you are not finishing your app)

Comment: no, never head of it before... do u suggest another way to write it since i just want to query for one single information and only once?

Comment: can you show us the file ConfiguracaoFirebase?

Comment: found the solution: i was calling FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
again... if you call this again it crashes!

Comment: @juliodidier If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question. Please also add your database structure and please responde with @.